# Framework7 running on browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I want to run a mobile app project built using Framework7 in browser instead of using PhoneGap.

I tried to run the project using my own local server but could not login maybe due to routing issue.

Any way to run the project in browser without PhoneGap? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it directly from local server by attach url to www directory like this:

```
http://localhost/mobile-app-project/www/
```

this url open app in your browser without using f7 run browser server.

Note: You most run `npm run build-dev` or `npm run build-prod` before access www (these command will build www directory)